# Cannot locate Servlet.class in CQ5 for the action "/bin/submitApplication"

Tags: aem, crx

I want to make some changes in a Project built on CQ5 ver 5.4.

There is a form submitting to a location "/bin/submitApplication" and I am unable to find the Servlet class for that. I have searched in CRX-DE Lite and there is no result.

Also if I go to URL http://vic.netpace.com/bin/submitApplication It give me the following exception that prints the class name but I cannot locate the class anywhere in CRX-DE

```
The requested URL /bin/submitApplication resulted in an error in com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet.

Request Progress:

      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/bin/submitApplication
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/bin/submitApplication resolves to Resource=ServletResource, servlet=com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet, path=/bin/submitApplication
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/bin/submitApplication', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='null'
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(ServletResource, servlet=com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet, path=/bin/submitApplication)}
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(ServletResource, servlet=com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet, path=/bin/submitApplication)} Using servlet com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/bin/submitApplication handled by Servlet=com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.portal.container.internal.request.PortalFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.netpace.vic.impl.filters.LoggingFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      0 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (MobileUtil.isMobileResource() returns false)
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet#0}
      1 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_START{handleError:status=405}
      4 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_END{3,handleError:status=405} Using handler org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.defaults.DefaultErrorHandlerServlet
      4 (2016-08-09 14:24:08) TIMER_END{4,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto `http://<your server>:<port>/system/console/components` and search for your class `com.netpace.vic.servlet.ApplicationServlet`, every servlet is registered as an OSGI component so you will find your servlet in components console.

Expand the component listing to see the details, from there you will get the bundle name in which that servlet is located. Copy that bundle name or note the bundle id.

Now goto `/system/console/bundles` and look for the bundle either using the name or id you copied from components console. You will be able to find the bundle, expand the bundle listing to see its details. In those details it will also specify location where bundle is installed/located.

You can goto that location in CRXDE, now there are two possibilities -

1. You will find a src folder there in CRXDE which should have code you are looking for.
2. Or you will know the name of JAR that is carrying your servlet. You can go and check your code repository/project for the java code of the servlet

> Also note that your servlet appears to be a form POST servlet so when
>   you are trying to access it via URL -
>   http://vic.netpace.com/bin/submitApplication you trying to hit a GET
>   request on it which probably is not supported by the servlet.